# Ansible can't SSH into the Vagrant Box

Tags: ssh, ansible, vagrant

Just playing around with Ansible and Vagrant.

I created this small Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.2"
  config.vm.hostname = "node1"

  config.vm.provision :vai do |ansible|
    ansible.inventory_dir = '/Users/Stinnux/Development/Vagrant/SingleNode'
    ansible.groups = {
      'gluster' => ['default']
    }
  end

 config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    ansible.inventory_path = "vagrant_ansible_inventory"
    ansible.verbose = "vvvvvvv"
  end

 config.vm.provider :parallels do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 2
    v.linked_clone = true
    v.update_guest_tools = true
  end
end
```

`vagrant ssh`  works

Even `ansible -i vagrant_ansible_inventory all -m ping` returns

```
default | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

However, `vagrant provision` returns:

```
10.211.55.72> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22 -o   'IdentityFile="/Users/Stinnux/Development/Vagrant/SingleNode/.vagrant/machines/default/parallels/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 10.211.55.72 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1479132943.61-145261399160047 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1479132943.61-145261399160047="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1479132943.61-145261399160047 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
fatal: [default]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-10.211.55.72-22-vagrant\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to 10.211.55.72 [10.211.55.72] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Connection established.\r\ndebug3: timeout: 10000 ms remain after connect\r\ndebug1: identity file /Users/Stinnux/Development/Vagrant/SingleNode/.vagrant/machines/default/parallels/private_key type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /Users/Stinnux/Development/Vagrant/SingleNode/.vagrant/machines/default/parallels/private_key-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0\r\ndebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1\r\ndebug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1\r\ndebug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host \"10.211.55.72\" from file \"/dev/null\"\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none\r\ndebug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none\r\ndebug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16\r\ndebug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16\r\ndebug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\r\ndebug1: Server host key: ECDSA 1f:de:15:a4:54:38:78:db:33:d1:1c:6d:c1:8a:37:6f\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host \"10.211.55.72\" from file \"/dev/null\"\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys\r\nWarning: Permanently added '10.211.55.72' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\ndebug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct\r\ndebug2: kex_derive_keys\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 1\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 0\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\r\ndebug1: Roaming not allowed by server\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent\r\ndebug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\r\ndebug2: key: /Users/Stinnux/Development/Vagrant/SingleNode/.vagrant/machines/default/parallels/private_key ((nil)), explicit\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\r\ndebug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password\r\ndebug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup publickey\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: publickey\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /Users/Stinnux/Development/Vagrant/SingleNode/.vagrant/machines/default/parallels/private_key\r\nno such identity: /Users/Stinnux/Development/Vagrant/SingleNode/.vagrant/machines/default/parallels/private_key: No such file or directory\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug1: No more authentication methods to try.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,password).\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: Found the reason.

The VAI plugin wrote the absolute path to the ssh private key into the inventory file. Since vagrant is running within the vm, the path should start with /vagrant instead.

Comment: Maybe useful to post this as an answer then. Could be useful to other people running into the same/similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. The VAI plugin wrote the absolute path to the ssh private key into the inventory file. Since vagrant is running within the vm, the path should start with /vagrant instead.

Comment: can you add an example with the working configuration? I'm having the same issue and am not sure where to add the /vagrant...

Comment: This is 5 years ago. I don't remember.